# Can someone point me in the right direction for making one javascript file run after another separate javascript file?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I have two games I made in Phaser js.  What my plan is, is to make a third js file thats only function is to proc the files.  What I mean is to initiate the controller file which will initiate the first game.  After that game is over by a certain condition, it will proc a global variable across files saying its done.  This will cause the master file to kill the first game and fire off the second.  Can someone direct me in how to do this?  I know these questions don't usually get answered without code so I'll include a pastebin link(since it's a lot of code) to the two games so you can verify that I've actually done the work.

Game 1: http://pastebin.com/cPTn26rz

Game 2: http://pastebin.com/2mCHvTLm

Comment: These two screenshots are both web pages.  Are you just trying to load another web page when the first game is done?  What about `window.location = xxx`.  You can pass data to the second page with a query parameter in the URL you load.

Comment: @jfriend00 They need to load from the same URL I believe.  If they loaded simultaneously that'd be fine, just as long as game 2 doesn't start until after game 1 is finished

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code I'm thinking you might be relatively new to Phaser, and you might not yet have heard about [Phaser's State Manager](http://phaser.io/docs/2.4.6/Phaser.StateManager.html).

In Phaser you can use states to create a standard game structure like this:

- Loading Screen
- Main Menu
- Game
- Game Over

In your particular case, you could just have something like this:

- Game 1
- Game 2

To start with I might recommend Bryan Bibat's [HTML 5 Shoot 'em Up in an Afternoon](https://leanpub.com/html5shootemupinanafternoon) (free to read online, but worth money). It was my first introduction to the state functionality.

Alternatively, Emanuele Feronato's [Understanding Phaser states](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2014/08/28/phaser-tutorial-understanding-phaser-states/) is pretty basic (and has a rough ending), but should provide a quick understanding of Phaser's states.

It might be a little advanced initially, but I actually got quite a bit out of [Interphase 1](http://phaser.io/interphase)'s state manager section, once you're ready to get a bit more advanced, but you should be able to get what you need from either of the tutorials above.

Comment: Thank you!  I had no clue this existed.  I've been working with Phaser for about a week now

Comment: Glad to help! And welcome to the next level of Phaser development :) I think you'll find the state functionality to be pretty helpful. I know that it personally made things easier for me. And just in case, you might want to consider looking at TypeScript as well. I had heard about it, but never actually used it until I started doing Phaser development. Either way, good luck!